# convert Multer.File object to File object

Tags: typescript, file, buffer, multer

convert multer object to file object

my response have multer object
and i need convert multer object to file object
what should i do?

- multer object
- Array.isArray(req.files) ? req.files.pop() : undefined;

```
[
  {
    fieldname: 'image',
    originalname: 'moon2.JPG',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 29 7c 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 0c 00 0f 01 02 00 06 00 00 00 9e 00 ... 282295 more bytes>,
    size: 282345
  }
]
```

- file object
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPJ4J.png)

i tried make binary string, base64 string, blob
but i cant make file object

- try convert another types

```
const photoBuffer = test?.buffer as Buffer
const binaryPhoto = Buffer.from(photoBuffer).toString('binary')
const base64Photo = Buffer.from(binaryPhoto).toString('base64')
```